# Python | проблема с FileIO

Tags: python, python-3.x, потоки-данных

Есть файл в `base64`:

```
data = '''UEsDBBQAAAAIABeAJVEPqTEW1gAAAJ0BAAAJAAAATWFpbi5qYXZhjVCxagMxDN0D+QfhyYZifFmP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'''
```

**Файл:** `test.zip`

Пытаюсь преобразовать данный `base64` в `io.FileIO`

```
import base64
import io
    
file = io.FileIO(base64.decodebytes(data.encode('UTF-8')), 'rb')
```

**Ошибка:**

```
file = io.FileIO(base64.decodebytes(data.encode('UTF-8')), 'rb')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

При этом, при попытке открыть байты в `io.BytesIO` - все работает и я могу сохранить оригинальный файл.

Comment: 1 - чем вас не устраивает BytesIO? 2 - зачем вы добавили `.decode('UTF-8').encode('UTF-8')` (это бессмысленное действие) ?

Comment: (Я знаю про бессмысленность. Я случайно это в ошибку добавил)))

Comment: Через `FileIO` я могу получить имя файла. Это важно для меня.

Comment: `Через FileIO я могу получить имя файла` - не можете. `FileIO` первым параметром принимает имя файла, но передав туда первым параметром данные вы никак оттуда имя файла не получите.

Comment: А, даже так. Тогда не расскажите в чем отличия между `BytesIO` и `FileIO`?

Comment: `FileIO` - это практически то же самое что `open`. По сути открывает файл по имени и позволяет работать с ним с помощью определенного набора операций. `BytesIO` - обертка над байтами, позволяющая работать с байтами как с файлом (теми же операциями).